# Critical nodes so there is no path between a node and a set of nodes

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory

We are given a graph with N nodes and M bidirectional edges, a subset of the nodes with K elements and a permutation of the nodes (without the first node). The goal is to "remove" the nodes in the order given by the permutation so node 1 can't be reached from the K nodes. 
When we remove a node, we also remove, its edges.

I'll give one example:

```
Input:
N = 6, M = 7, K = 3
the subset of K nodes: 3 4 6
the permutation: 2 3 4 6 5
the edges: (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4), (5, 6)

Output: 4
If we "remove" nodes 2, 3, 4, 6, there is no path between 1 and 3, 4, 6
```

What I've tried so far is to eliminate the nodes in the order given by permutation one by one, and then test if there is a path from node 1 to the nodes in the subset with a DFS. The complexity is O(N * (N + M)) and I want to do it in better complexity.